# Extracting Text from PDF Docs into separate new filename Docs

Tags: pdf, c++, c#, c

I have a mass number of PDF files (>2k files) that look something similar to this
[(Image of Sample PDF)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5OcS.png)

I have list indentations (A, B, C, D), followed by text. What I'm trying to achieve is to extract each paragraph within each list indentation in its own PDF.

For example, original file name is: samplepdf.pdf

extraction will look something similar to this:

samplepdf_A.pdf  - text within indentation A (lorem ipsum)

samplepdf_B.pdf  - text within indentation B (Vestibulum eget)

samplepdf_C.pdf  - text within indentation C (Sed mollis erat)

samplepdf_D.pdf  - text within indentation D (Praesent ac sapien)

I've searched within GitHub but I couldn't really find what I need.

Edit: I'm open to other languages too.

In the end, the question is: Can I extract the text between the indentations into separate files?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: also if there are better ways (other than C/C++/C#) to do it let me know!
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company I work for has a professional .NET library that supports parsing documents (including PDF) and extracting the text from them. There's a [C# tutorial here](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/tutorials/dotnet-console-parse-the-text-of-a-document.html) that shows how to get text from a PDF document using the LEADTOOLS SDK.

Once you have the text as shown in the tutorial, you can obtain the exact location of every word by calling the [_pageText.BuildWords Method](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/dox/documentpagetext-buildwords.html), which will give you a list of all words, and the location of every word in the _pageText.Words Property. You can then determine from the location of each word the exact paragraph or “indentation” that the word belongs to.

If you would like to try the SDK, there’s a free evaluation edition on [this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).

Comment: One question though, I need them extracted into other PDF files as shown in the example above

Comment: If you can send me a link if something like this is available at your company. Thanks once again!

Comment: I have written [a code sample here](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t18094-) that shows how to split the words of a PDF page to 2 separate PDF files. The sample checks every word: if it’s above the center line of the page, it adds it to the first PDF file and if it’s below the center line, it adds the word to the second PDF file. You can change the code to examine the words in a different way and to split the page contents to 4 or as many files as you need.

Comment: Hi Amin!
Thanks for giving out this example. I'll check it out. If I have any questions I'll ask you, if you don't mind :-)

Comment: Hi!

I'm having some code problems with the code you wrote. It's driving me crazy with its errors!!!

Err1- Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to 'System.IntPtr'


Err2+3+4- 'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetHdc/ReleaseHdc/Dispose' and no accessible extension method 'GetHdc/ReleaseHdc/Dispose' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found
The type or namespace name 'DocumentWriterEmfPage' could not be found

Comment: I have posted a reply to the original post [here.](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/m51889-#post51889) In the new post, I added a C# project that uses the code and explained the needed references and other requirements for the project to build successfully. If you still face problems, send full information about your project and its details to support@leadtools.com or use the online chat service. Both email and chat support are free of charge.